# class function toString() C++

Tags: c++, function, set, tostring

I have a class called Set with a function defined that is supposed to return the set as its string equivalent. I am having major issues with understanding how to implement this as my teacher has not done a good job of explaining what to do. Any directional help or explanation would be extremely appreciated. I have posted the setup wanted by my professor.

edit1: to add for clarity, I understand how to implement most of the other functions offhand but for some reason the toString() function is just really not clicking with me. Also the names of the functions were given to us specifically to use this way so Union is supposed to be capitalized as it interferes with another command.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>


class Set
{
public:
    void add(int i);
    bool belongs(int i);
    void difference(Set B);
    void Union(Set B);
    void intersect(Set B);
    std::string toString();
};

int main()
{
    Set A;
    Set B;

    std::cout << "printing A" << std::endl;
    A.toString();
    std::cout << std::endl << "printing B" << std::endl;
    B.toString();
    std::cout << std::endl << "adding 12 to A" << std::endl;
    A.add(12);
    std::cout << std::endl << "printing A" << std::endl;
    A.toString();
    std::cout << std::endl << "does 4 belong to A" << std::endl;
    A.belongs(4);
    std::cout << std::endl << "does 11 belong to A" << std::endl;
    A.belongs(11);
    std::cout << std::endl << " remove B from A" << std::endl;
    A.difference(B);
    std::cout << std::endl << "printing A" << std::endl;
    A.toString();
    std::cout << std::endl << "union of A and B" << std::endl;
    A.Union(B);
    std::cout << std::endl << "printing A" << std::endl;
    A.toString();
    std::cout << std::endl << "intersecting A and B" << std::endl;
    A.intersect(B);
    std::cout << std::endl << "printing A" << std::endl;
    A.toString();
}

//add the number i to the set
void Set::add(int i)
{

}

//return true if i is a member of the set
bool Set::belongs(int i)
{

}

//removes B from the set A where A is the current set so A=A-B
void Set::difference(Set B)
{

}

//performs A U B where A is the current set and the result is stored in A
void Set::Union(Set B)
{

}

//performs A B where A is the current set and the result is stored in A
void Set::intersect(Set B)
{

}

//displays the set in roster notation {1, 2, 3} etc
std::string Set::toString()
{

}
```

Comment: So what is the actual question? We're not here to either explain what your teacher wants you do to or do that for you.

Comment: Unless it's a requirement for this exercise, I suggest you create an `to_string` function, which will then mirror the functionality of [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). Your function could of course use an existing `toString` member function in the object.

Comment: Also please try to keep names and symbols consistent. The name `Union` stands out compared to the other member functions. Consistency makes code easier to read, understand and maintain (very important for bigger projects). And note that all upper-case names are usually used for macros or other symbolic constants. Work on the good habits from the start, and you won't have to think about it later.

Comment: You are asking too soon, I'm afraid. `Set` does not yet have any members to convert TO a string. That said, starting with the `toString`method is the right idea. It will be invaluable when debugging the other functions.

Answer (score 2):

What your professor wants you to do is write a function `std::string Set::toString(){ ... }` which will return a `std::string` that contains the elements of your objects internal container (I suspect probably a `std::vector` based on your functions) that will return a string that contains the elements in the correct format.

You will need to look into how to iterate over the internal container and append elements to the string you are returning using [`string::append`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/). Hopefully this is enough direction to actually get started on the function and implement it as it is fairly straight forward. You'll probably need to use the [`to_string()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) method to convert integers to strings before appending.

Comment: @keeperkell13 Welcome